# Authorization Oauth2 bad request for PowerBI user

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I am building a sample ASP.NET 5 (vNext) web application to act on behalf PowerBI users through Power BI API.

I followed all the steps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn877542.aspx) to register my application and I have the ClientId.
The app was added to my Azure Active Directory *realavaloro.onmicrosoft.com*

My web application is able to redirect the user to the authority `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/`passing as query parameters the `response_type`, `clientId`, `resource` and `redirect_uri`

```
 "response_type": "code"
 "resourceUri":  "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
 "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "redirectUri": "http://localhost:59136/"
```

The browser is properly redirected to the microsoft page and the user enters his Power BI credentials. If authenticated, it is redirected to the redirect_uri with the code + session_state

The problem is that I don't fully understand this mechanism.. :)

If I use my PowerBI test account credentials (diego@*realavaloro.onmicrosoft.com*) the authentication is successful and the browser is redirected properly with code + session_state

But if I try to authenticate with other PowerBI credentials, for example joe@companyb.com it fails to authenticate with the Bad Request message:
`AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 408c866f-ad71-4354-b9fd-c954cae84dd7 was not found in the directory companyb.com`

I thought any user with an account in PowerBI would be able to, through our web application, user his PowerBI account through the API provided our web application has permission.

But it seems that if we want that to happen with this approach **every user would need their own Azure Active Directory to authenticate against**.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Is there any option to allow our application act on behalf ANY Power BI user?

Thank you!

PS: I built my test web application following guidelines at https://github.com/PowerBI/getting-started-web-app-asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer myself. The reason I my web application couldn't authenticate external users with their Power BI credentials was (duh!) because I had not configured my web application in Azure AD as **multi-tenant**.

Thanks to this great presentation https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3551 I found some good answers including the meaning of multi-tenant :)

I still have to investigate the Azure libraries to manage all these Authentication headers for me and get my head around OAuth2 but at least I can say now that the authentication works for external users.